# haml is not allowing multiple forms in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, haml

```
#social_list
  = form_tag notes_path, class: 'form clearfix', id: 'add_post_form',multipart: true, remote: true 
  .control-group
    = text_area_tag "comment[text]", '', :placeholder => 'Post to the community', :cols => nil, :rows => nil, :class => 'mention expand-without-submit'
    = file_field_tag "picture", id:'image_upload', accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg'
    = submit_tag "Post your message", class: 'btn btn-success btn-mini'

  = form_tag images_path
    = submit_tag 'asad'  

  = render "dashboards/activity_stream_filter"
```

I want to add second form but it is giving me this error.

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end
```

I guess some scoping issue is messed up or is the possible to have multiples form in single page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`form_tag` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) takes a block for the form contents. In your first form you have’t provided a block at all since nothing is indented below it. In the second case there is content indented below, but you haven’t included the `do`. This second case is causing the syntax error.

What I think you want is

```haml
#social_list
  - # note 'do' added to this line:
  = form_tag notes_path, class: 'form clearfix', id: 'add_post_form',multipart: true, remote: true do
    - # this section indented:
    .control-group
      = text_area_tag "comment[text]", '', :placeholder => 'Post to the community', :cols => nil, :rows => nil, :class => 'mention expand-without-submit'
      = file_field_tag "picture", id:'image_upload', accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg'
      = submit_tag "Post your message", class: 'btn btn-success btn-mini'

  - # 'do'added to next line
  = form_tag images_path do
    = submit_tag 'asad'  

  = render "dashboards/activity_stream_filter"
```